# Erro ao tentar fazer integração de notificação cloud com firebase em Dart

Tags: firebase, push-notification, dart, flutter

Galera, estou tentando enviar push notifications para os usuários da minha aplicação em Flutter, no entanto, quando faço o método

```
void initState() {
\\\\\
}
```

e configuro todo o sistema de notificação, o compilador me retorna um erro de: 
**This method overrides a method annotated as @mustCallSuper in 'State', but does not invoke the overridden method.**

Não estou entendendo a causa do erro, o processo de configuração da notificação está correto, segue o código completo aqui:

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {    
String textValue = 'Hello World';
  FirebaseMessaging firebaseMessaging = new FirebaseMessaging();
  @override  
  void initState() {
    firebaseMessaging.configure(
      onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> msg){
        print(" onLaunch called");
      },
      onResume: (Map<String, dynamic> msg){
        print(" onResume called");
      },
      onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> msg){
        print(" onMessage called");
      }
    );
    firebaseMessaging.requestNotificationPermissions(
      const IosNotificationSettings(
        sound: true,
        alert: true,
        badge: true
      )
    );
    firebaseMessaging.onIosSettingsRegistered.listen((IosNotificationSettings setting){
    print('IOS Setting Registed');
    });
    firebaseMessaging.getToken().then((token){
      update(token);
    });
  }
  update(String token){
    print(token);
    textValue = token;
    setState((){

    });
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Na antiga atualização não era necessário o comando **super.initState();** após o

```
void initState(){

}
```

No entanto, atualmente é necessário o comando no bloco, caso alguém tenha o mesmo problema que o meu, possivelmente esta é a solução, qualquer coisa tentem dar um flutter upgrade no console tbm.